# convert pointer value to string and back again

Tags: c++, pointers

if I have a pointer to int , and it's value is `0x0012FF7C` how can I store this value in a string , and then make the reverse ( I mean convert the value stored in string to `int*`)

I need this way because I need to send a memory location between two process in PVM, so I need to send the value of a pointer as a string, and receive this string in the second process and store it's value in a pointer

Comment: Since we are talking about different processes, does that not imply that the memory may be mapped to different virtual addresses? And in that case, would you not need to transfer the result of `(ptr - baseptr)`, which would yield an integer, not a pointer?

Comment: @gha.st I'm using PVM in one computer, so the processes should use the same RAM right ?

Comment: you can just copy the value to the char array, append null-terminated byte if needed after the last byte of the address

Comment: @MGCR7 not actually. In an environment with memory management, each process will have a seperate virtual address so you cannot just pass the pointers to those memory places but you need to use inter-process communication

Comment: What you plan to do doesn't work. You cannot assume that pointers represent the same section of memory in two different processes (and for most OS that's a fact). You seriously should have a look into interprocess communication and serialization techniques.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is pointless. I'm close voting, because other readers finding this question might have the idea, such technique could properly work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plan doesn't sound like it's going to work, since a valid memory address in one process might be an invalid memory address in another process... Nevertheless, here is how you can do it:

- In the first process, call `sprintf(str,"%p",ptr)`
- In the second process, call `sscanf(str,"%p",&ptr)`
- On a 32-bit system, you'll need to declare `char str[8+1]`
- On a 64-bit system, you'll need to declare `char str[16+1]`

---

Having said that, you probably need to send **the contents of the memory address**, or if too long for this purpose, then write them into a file in one process and read them from that file in the other process.

Comment: I'm using PVM in one computer, so the processes should use the same RAM right ?

Comment: @MGCR7: Are you running the same executable in two different processes?

Comment: No, each executable contains it's own code

Comment: @MGCR7: So what makes you think that you can safely access that memory address in the other process (and of course, read the value that you need from that address)? You probably need to pass the value itself as a string (or if it's too long, then perhaps write it into a file and let the other process read it from that file).

Comment: I'm having an array of bool in 1st process, and I need to change it's values in the 2nd process , and making some work in 1st process depending on the values of this array . so i think to send the address of this array to second process

Comment: @MGCR7 _'so i think to send the address of this array to second process'_ As others already mentioned: **That won't work!**

Answer (score 0):

This should work to convert to string:

```
std::size_t i = 0x0012FF7C;
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << std::setw(size_t(void*)) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << i;
assert(buffer.str() == "0012FF7C");
```

For the reading you can use a std::istringstream in a similar way (though I think you need to read as a string, then convert it to an int depending on the base).

That said, your question makes abstraction of address virtualization (depending where you run your code and under which conditions, it may not work).

Answer (score 0):

Bufferoverflow-safe, old school C version:

```
  char addr[0xf];
  snprintf(addr, 0xf, "0x%X", ptr);
```

Comment: well it **will** overflow in a 64-bit environment. And the format "%#0X" is better

Comment: You're right, the addr buffer wont fit a 64-bit pointer. I stand corrected. Always use snprintf instead of sprintf though